# GET and POST between a UWP Application and an HTTP Server

Tags: python, database, server, uwp

I've just recently started trying to setup an HTTP server with Python on my computer to try to communicate with a UWP application that I'm building. My overall goal is to host this server online and send photos from the UWP application to the HTTP server and then run a Python/C++ script on the images. Once that has finished processing, I want to output some data into a file and then send that back to the UWP application. I'm new to servers and databases and so I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

As I mentioned, I've set up a very basic server with the following Python code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):


self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
    if(self.path == "/test"):
        exec(open("test.py").read())

def do_POST(self):
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
    post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself

    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write("POST request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Server stopped.")
        webServer.server_close()
```

And I am able to successfully GET and POST but now I'm not sure what to do. Do I need to setup a database to store any of the data that I post? If so, what's the best way to go about that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a database.

Use the code below to set up a secure socket-based http server. It has some basic protections against specific types of DOS-Attacks, and allows you to ban specific addresses from accessing your service.

Pay attention to the comments: They explain the important code parts. Make sure to configure your server safely. Do not rely on data coming from your application. An Attacker, for example, could create a malicious request, looking like a normal request from your application. DONT insert invalid data into the Response structure, or you will end up with a 500 Internal Server Error reply.

This code has no dependencies; it can run on any OS, as it is not using OS-specific API's. (Tested on Python 3.9.0, Windows 10.)

```
import socket
import threading
import ssl
import time
import tempfile
import os
hostname="localhost"    #hostName in your code
port=8080               #serverPort in your code - default HTTP Port is 80
banned_IPs=()           #Every IP in this list is denied access to your service

#SSL-Specific settings
SSLEnabled=False        #set to True if you got a valid SSL/TLS configuration for your server, and want to provide a secure version of the service
SSLContext=None         #must be set if SSLEnabled - set to ssl.SSLContext with proper configuration - see documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html
SSLPort=None            #Port for the secure version of your service - must be set if SSLEnabled is True and may not hav the same value as port

#These are some security limits - change them if necessary
MaxIpConnections=1024   #Maximum Connections per IP address per minute - DDOS-Protection
MaxHeaderSize=8192      #8 KB maximum Header Size - Protection against malicious clients trying to fill up device-memory
MaxBodySize=1073741824  #1 GB maximum Payload Size - malicious clients may try 

to overload memory with extremely large payloads

#Internal variables:
_clientRegister={}      #DDOS-Protection
_max_blank_packets=128  #Detect wheter a socket has been closed

#Configuration - I use IPv4 here - replace AF_INET by AF_INET6 for IPv6
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if SSLEnabled:
    SSLSock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def IO(request,response):
    """do something with the data here.
As i don't know, what you want to do, I will do nothing here."""
    pass
class Request(object):
    """A HTTP request"""
    method=None     #GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,...
    route=None      #path, /example,/foo/example,/,...
    body=None       #Filename of a File containing the request's Body, None if no body was present.
    proto="HTTP/1.1"#Protocol, either "HTTP/1.1" or "HTTP/1.0"
    headers={}      #Headers, having a structure like {key:[value[,value[,...]]],[key:[...][,...]]}
    ip=None         #I don't need to explain that
    localport=None  #The Locally used port, one of port, SSLPort
    secure=False    #wheter the request wa made over TLS/SSL
    remoteport=None #Client-Side port. Your'e probaly not gonna need it
    socket=None     #underlying socket. Your'e probaly not gonna need it
    def __init__(self,method,route,proto,headers,bodyfile,addr,lport,sock):
        self.method=method.decode("ascii")
        self.route=route.decode("ascii")
        self.proto=proto.decode("ascii")
        for i in headers:
            k=i
            self.headers[k.decode("ascii")]=[]
            for v in headers[i]:
                self.headers[k.decode("ascii")].append(v.decode("ascii"))
        self.body=bodyfile
        self.ip=addr[0]
        self.port=addr[1]
        self.localport=lport
        self.secure=(self.localport==SSLPort)
        self.socket=sock
class Response(object):
    """A HTTP Response"""
    status=200      #Statuscode
    statustext="OK" #Statustext
    proto="HTTP/1.1"#Protocol, either "HTTP/1.1" or "HTTP/1.0"
    headers={"Connection":["close"]}#Same structure as in Request
    body=None       #Filename for Responsebody, use tempfile.mktemp() for temporary file.
    socket=None     #underlying socket. Your'e probaly not gonna need it
"Now some Internal functions - just ignore them"
#Some binding + listening stuff
sock.bind((hostname,port))
sock.listen(32)
if SSLEnabled:
    SSLSock.bind((hostname,SSLPort))
    SSLSock.listen(32)
def checkIp(ip):
    if _clientRegister[ip][1]<=time.time():
        del _clientRegister[ip]
def garbage_collector_thread():
    while True:
        try:
            for i in _clientRegister:
                checkIp(i)
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(30)#Garbage-Collection every half minute
def client_thread(cli,addr):
    ip=addr[0]
    if ip in banned_IPs:
        cli.close()
        return
    if ip in _clientRegister:
        _clientRegister[ip][0]+=1
        if _clientRegister[ip][0]>MaxIpConnections:
            cli.close()
            return
    else:
        _clientRegister[ip]=[0,time.time()+60]
    if cli.getsockname()[1]==SSLPort:
        cli=SSLContext.wrap(cli,True)
    header=b""
    blank=0
    try:
        while not b"\r\n\r\n" in header:
            block=cli.recv(1024)
            if block==b"":
                blank+=1
            else:
                blank=0
            if blank>=_max_blank_packets:
                cli.close()
                return
            if len(header)>MaxHeaderSize:
                cli.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 431 Header Fields Too Large\r\nConnection: closed\r\n\r\n")
                cli.close()
                return
            header+=block
        header,body=header.split(b"\r\n\r\n",1)
        head={}
        status,*header=header.split(b"\r\n")
        for i in header:
            k,v=i.split(b": ",1)
            if k in header:
                head[k].append(v)
            else:
                head[k]=[v]
        method,route,proto=status.split(b" ",2)
        if b"Content-Length" in header:
            v=int(header[b"Content-Length"][0])
            if v>MaxBodySize:
                cli.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 413 Payload too large\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
                cli.close()
                return
            size=len(body)
            returnfile=tempfile.mktemp()
            f=open(returnfile,"wb")
            f.write(returnfile)
            while size<v:
                block=cli.recv(1024)
                if block==b"":
                    blank+=1
                else:
                    blank=0
                if blank>=_max_blank_packets:
                    cli.close()
                    f.close()
                    os.remove(returnfile)
                    return
                size+=len(block)
                f.write(block)
            f.close()
        elif body!=b"":
            cli.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
            cli.close()
            return
        else:
            returnfile=None
        request=Request(method,route,proto,head,returnfile,addr,cli.getsockname()[1],cli)
        response=Response()
        response.socket=cli
    except ConnectionError:
        cli.close()
        return
    except:
        try:
            cli.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
        except:
            pass
        cli.close()
        return
    try:
        IO(request,response)
    except:
        try:
            cli.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
            cli.close()
            return
        except:
            cli.close()
            return
    try:
        if response.body!=None:
            response.headers["Content-Length"]=[str(os.path.getsize(response.body))]
        r=b" ".join([response.proto.encode("ascii"),str(response.status).encode("ascii"),response.statustext.encode("ascii")])
        r+=b"\r\n"
        for i in response.headers:
            k=i
            for v in response.headers[k]:
                r+=k.encode("ascii")+b": "+v.encode("ascii")+b"\r\n"
        r+=b"\r\n"
        cli.sendall(r)
        if response.body!=None:
            f=open(response.body,"rb")
            while True:
                block=f.read(1024)
                if block==b"":
                    break
                cli.sendall(block)
            f.close()
        cli.close()
        return
    except:
        try:
            cli.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
            cli.close()
            return
        except:
            cli.close()
            return
def SSLAccept(sock):
    while True:
        cli,addr=sock.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=client_thread,args=(cli,addr)).start()
if SSLEnabled:
    threading.Thread(target=SSLAccept,args=(SSLSock,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=garbage_collector_thread).start()
while True:
    cli,addr=sock.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=client_thread,args=(cli,addr)).start()
```